# When using React Helmet in dynamic pages component, meta from Helmet is loaded instead of JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I have a component that renders articles:

```
    if (!article) {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Box
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
          minHeight="100vh"
        >
          <CircularProgress />
        </Box>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet
        title={article?.title}
        meta={[
          {
            name: "description",
            content: article.main.slice(
              0,
              article.main.indexOf(".", article.main.indexOf(".") + 1)
            ),
            charSet: "utf-8",
          },
        ]}
      />
      <Header />
      <div className="articles container">
        <p className="articles__date">{article?.date}</p>
        <h1 className="articles__main">{article?.title}</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSpoiler(!spoiler)}
          className="articles__spoiler"
        >
          Содержание
          <svg
            className={spoiler ? "articles__spoiler-svg-active" : ""}
            width="9"
            height="7"
            viewBox="0 0 9 7"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M1 2L4.50259 4.99698L8 1.99396"
              stroke="#8599C7"
              strokeWidth="2"
              strokeLinecap="round"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
        {spoiler ? (
          <div>
            <div className="articles__wrapper">
              <div className="articles__wrapper-text">
                <p> {article?.main}</p>
                <div
                  className="articles__wrapper-customText"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article?.editingHTML }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="articles__wrapper-image">
                <img src={article?.img} alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
      <Calculator />
      <UsefulMaterials />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

If you go to the page of this component with React Route, then everything works fine. Styles and JS are successfully imported.
But when you immediately follow the link, for example, "site.com/article/53", then instead of styles and JS I get html layout with meta from React Helmet:

[image: CSS]

[image: JS]

Before building everything works fine, but after building and publishing to the server, an error is detected.
Tell me please, what could be the problem?